# PHPUnit Ansicon is not showing colors

Tags: phpunit, windows-8.1, git-bash, ansicon

Operating System: Windows 8.1 (64 bit)

Terminal: Git Bash

Purpose: Show colors in PHPUnit command results

Process followed:

1. Downloaded https://github.com/downloads/adoxa/ansicon/ansi160.zip
2. Extracted the file into C:\ansicon
3. Added C:\ansicon\x64 in "Path" user variables.
4. Opened Git Bash as administrator
5. Moved into C:\ansicon\x64 and executed `ansicon -i` without any errors.
6. Restarted Git Bash and moved into My test project.
7. Executed phpunit --colors TestFile.php

Problem: The result is showing but without any colors.

Question: What have I done wrong? How to solve it?